# how to install CU in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointadmin, sharepoint-upgrade

I have a SharePoint server with the following build version,

**Version : 14.0.4763.1000.**

Under **Manage Patch Status** I can find the following products with the same above mentioned version,

1.Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010

2.Microsoft® Office Web Apps

3.Microsoft® Project Server 2010

Now I need to install the December 2012 CU, I read that December 2012 CU is a Post-SP1 hotfix,

1.Should I install both the SharePoint foundation SP1 and SharePoint Server SP1 and whats the order of installation?

2.How to find which all language packs are installed in the server.?

3.Should I install both the SharePoint foundation december 2012 CU and SharePoint Server december 2012 CU and whats the order of installation?

4.As I can see Project server 2010 in the sever Should I go for "SharePoint Server 2010 with Project Server December 2012 CU" ?

5.What about the Office web apps, what all to be installed for it to be upgraded.?

Kindly request you to provide me the links for downloads and steps for the installation to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

There is a definite guide on TechNet site. I will not replicate it here. Please go through it here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263467(v=office.14).aspx

You can also download this comprehensive whitepaper:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26573